# selenium IDE displays hidden div then immediately closes it

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a hidden div element that when I click the link the visibility changes.  In my Selenium IDE script I click the link and I see the div open but then it immediately closes.  The rest of the scripts run, but in a demo I would like to keep that div open.

My steps are:

- click [Link that shows hidden div]
  -->It is here that it displays and then immediately hides it.
- focus [element inside div]
- assertValue [target element]

Is there a setting that I need or a step that needs to be added?

Comment: Could you show your webpage? Is it public?

Comment: @kotoj - no this is an internal site.

Comment: when you click link manually the div closes as well?

Comment: @kotoj - no there is an ""X" the user can press to close the screen.  That is the only way that I've seen to close that div.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to suggest. But there are some things that you can try.

- First of all maybe your div is going to hide when link is not under
  the mouse. Than you can use **mouseOver**
- Maybe if you need just to verify variable you do not need even see
  the div. Selenium IDE can take the value from element that is not
  visible. It is not a fare play but sometimes you can do it.
- Another way is to use javascript to bring your div to the light:

  ```
  getEval | window.document.getElementById('your_divs_id').set_attribute('style','');
  ```
- The most brutal and not trustable way to try to do it to add command

  ```
  getEval | window.stop()
  ```

right after the click.